# Identifying all Kusama blocks with era payouts

Tags: kusama, staking

I am trying to find all the blocks at which an era payout has occurred on Kusama.

For that I have queried both these events, `staking.erapaid` and its predecessor `staking.erapayout`, which contain the payout and the corresponding era.

However, `staking.erapayout` only goes back to era 760, so the question is, how can we find the blocks where era payouts occurred before this point?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to inspect historical events is to use tools that expose historical metadata. For example, based on Kusama Subscan:

- In runtime spec [1058](https://kusama.subscan.io/runtime/Staking?version=1058) neither of the events mentioned above existed.
- In runtime spec [1062](https://kusama.subscan.io/runtime/Staking?version=1062), `EraPayout` was added.
- Later, in runtime spec [9090](https://kusama.subscan.io/runtime/Staking?version=9090), `EraPaid` appears, which seems to be a mere rename of the former.

Please note that as per the documentation of this event, it is indicating the amount of rewards that was minted for the entire staking system.

> In general, renaming events is not a good practice, as it leads to such complications, and can easily break frontend libraries.